# How can I import Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on an external SSD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I encountered a few error messages, namely a `Server execution failed` message when trying to import the Windows Subsystem for Linux version of Ubuntu to an **external** SSD. After re-enabling the optional Windows feature for WSL, a new `Unspecified Error` appeared.

I have already exported a ubuntu.tar file, but I cannot import it to a new location (my external SSD) because of the error mentioned above. I also enabled and re-enabled the optional features for WSL.

I've been following this StackOverflow post for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779801/move-wsl-bash-on-windows-root-filesystem-to-another-hard-drive, but got stuck on the importation step.

No matter which directory I execute the command from, I get the same message. I'm not sure what's causing it.

My goal is to import the ubuntu.tar file onto an external SSD because my current C:\ Drive is running low on storage. Then afterward, I'm hoping that WSL would function normally (including updates).

I am now wondering if it's even possible to import WSL on an external drive? Perhaps that could be the source of the problem?

[image]

UPDATE:

WSL does work from Windows, and the WSL command `wsl -l -v` does return a response after reenabling the WSL Windows Optional Feature.

[image: wsl -l -v]

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119918/discussion-on-question-by-alvin-how-can-i-import-windows-subsystem-for-linux-ws). Its probably a better medium for extended trouble shooting.